# Retain a wildcard while replacing string with regex

Tags: notepad++, regex

I am using Notepad++ to do this:

I was able to find the appropriate pattern to match my string, which would be:
(.*)myemail[at]gmail.com

What I need to do now is insert a line break and some additional stuff, only before the lines ending with my email adress.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

```
 Replace      (.*name@gmail.com)$
 With         \nSome text\n\1
```

Remember to check the Regular expression check box in the search mode.

Comment: Thank you, you saved me many additional hours trying to figure that out!